# Getting the array Class<?> of a given class

Tags: java, reflection

Given a `Class<?>` that describes class `A`, is it somehow possible to get the `Class<?>` that matches the class `A[]`?

```
Class<?> clazz = A.class;
Class<?> arrayclazz = clazz.toArray(); // ??

assert arrayclazz.equals(A[].class);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz, 0).getClass()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,%20int))

Comment: Thats a neat trick. But is there anyway to save the new instance?

Comment: @Idan K You could hack the strings, but the overhead of creating a zero-length array is tiny. Probably less than that of creating intermediate `String`s and `StringBuilder`s and then parsing that and looking up the classes. Of course, best would be to avoid reflection and indeed reference arrays altogether.

Comment: @Tom: that makes sense. I'm just a little surprised there isn't anything in Java to do this directly without resorting to these kind of tricks.

Comment: @Idan K It's not like such a thing should get used much!

Comment: @Tim: agreed. The only reason I had to resort to this trickery is because of this http://ideone.com/OChQB The first call to `getGenericReturnType` returned `int[]` but the second returned `GenericArrayType` and I was only able to get the component from it, i.e. `int`.

Answer (score -1):

use `A[].class`. I hope this help.

Comment: `A` was used as an example. I actually just have a `Class<?>` in hand.