# Obtain array Class given element Class

Tags: java

Suppose we have a class `Class<E> elementClass` and we want to obtain the class of an array which would consist of elements of class `elementClass`.  For years, java did not offer any elegant way of accomplishing this, so we have been instantiating a throwaway array just to get its class, like this:

```
Class<?> arrayClass = Array.newInstance( elementClass, 0 ).getClass();
```

- This question: [Getting the array Class<?> of a given class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091348/getting-the-array-class-of-a-given-class) asked 4 years ago has an answer which shows precisely this inelegant method, and
- This question: [Java reflection getting array class of a given class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617947/java-reflection-getting-array-class-of-a-given-class) asked 3 years ago shows an additional method which I am not sure is any less inelegant.

So, has anything improved in this regard in java during the last three years?  Do we have any decent way of obtaining the class of an array given the class of the element?

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think if something have changed regarding that, even in [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) it's the same as [Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html)

Comment: Creating a zero-length array is very cheap. What's the problem here? Is this an action you'll be doing 1000's of times per second?

Comment: @Bohemian to me, it is not an issue of performance, it is an issue of elegance.